# What does the workplace trust checkbox do in Github Copilot Extension for VS Code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

So I rightclicked on my github copilot on bottom right of my VS code IDE, and saw the Workspace Trust unchecked.

[image]

What does this do if checked? And is there any performance improvement expected if checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This confused me as well, but **it's not a feature of Copilot**. You get this menu from clicking on the `status bar`, and as you see, the `GitHub Copilot (Extension)` is just one of many items you can add to the status bar.

Activating it will show a lock symbol on the left of the status bar.